# When does longest permutation cycle = p-1? (where p is prime)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Taking p = 7 as an example, let c*r1 = r2 (p)

If c = 2 we get

0 1 2 3 4 5 6

0 2 4 6 1 3 5

or (1 2 4) (3 6 5), so longest cycle is 3 < p-1

But for c = 3 we get

0 1 2 3 4 5 6

0 3 6 2 5 1 4

or (1 3 2 6 4 5), so longest cycle is 6 = p-1

So my question is, given p a prime, for what c do we get a cycle of length p-1?

I am probably using the wrong words so feel free to edit my question so it makes sense!

Comment: What is $r_1,r_2$? Also, do you mean $cr_1\equiv r_2\mod{p}$?

Comment: That is it exactly. 0 <= r < p. Thank you

Comment: could you clarify how $c$ relates to the permutations you list? The equation you've written is currently not clearly related to what's below.

Comment: Well no wonder it wasn't clear, I typed in the wrong example. does it make sense now?

Comment: If I understood it correctly you are asking when the permutation $[x\mapsto ax]$ of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ has maximal possible order $p-1$. This happens, if and only if $a$ is a so called [primitive root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) modulo $p$. Primitive roots exist for all primes, but there is no known formula saying which multipliers $a$ will work. However, if $a$ is on primitive root modulo $p$, then there is a way of generating all of them. They are the remainders of $a^k$ (modulo $p$) for exponents $k$ such that $\gcd(k,p-1)=1$.

Comment: For example with $p=7$ you found out that $3$ is a primitive root. The exponents $k, 1\le k<7-1$, such that $\gcd(k,6)=1$ are $k=1$ and $k=5$. Therefore there are exactly two primitive roots modulo $7$. Namely $3^1=3$ and $$3^5=243=238+5=7\cdot34+5\equiv 5\pmod 7.$$

Comment: If your 'a' is like my 'c' then I think what you said is indeed my question. I am taking all the numbers from 0 to p-1, multiplying them by a constant c then assigning 0->c*0, 1->c*1, 2->c*2, 3->c*3 etc. I think this gives what is called a permutation which can be expressed as one or more cycles. I want to know, given a prime p, which c yields a cycle of length p-1. Sure seems like you answered that question, which is that there is no way to tell. C has to be a primitive root, but that doesn't help because there is no formula for a primitive root.

Comment: Can you tell me if 3 is always a primitive root of a prime?